# Как узнать точное время, если доступ к сети не постоянен?

Tags: java, android

Для работы приложения берется время UTC+0, но нужны точные минуты и секунды. 
Так как доступ к сети не постоянен то точное время не всегда можно определить. Если способ еще как то определить точное время.

Comment: *доступ к сети не постоянен* какова максимальная продолжительность перерыва связи? Какова девиация часов системы? Какие постоянно доступные ресурсы умеют выполнять роль сервера времени, и какая девиация у максимально точного и стабильного из них?

Comment: проще всего проинитить время из системного, а потом дергать сервер раз в n таймюнитов и при изменении статуса сети. При обращении к сети брать не время с сервера, а РАЗНИЦУ между временем с сервера и локальным временем